# How to insert font awesome icon into text input?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, webfonts

How can I insert a calendar web font icon into my input field?

[image]

HTML:

```
<input class="start_date" type="text">
```

CSS:

```
.start_date:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f073";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<input>` is a self-closing tag, you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2591460/1654265) have any `:before` or `:after` pseudo element in it. You could wrap it into a `<label>` or `<span>` so and attach it there.

```css
.start_date:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f073";
}

.start_date:before,
.start_date input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<label class="start_date">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Date">
</label>
```

Here is an example of having the icon positioned inside the input field.

```css
.start_date {
  position: relative;
}

.start_date:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 14px;
  content: "\f073";
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.start_date input {
  text-indent: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<label class="start_date">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Date" />
</label>
```