# How could I Cange trigger from input[type="file"] to a span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I wanna click on my Styled span tag, and open the upload file window, that's what my input[type="file"] do.

**PS**: I can't change my HTML code.

I got this code from this other question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453728/how-do-i-add-a-font-awesome-icon-to-file-input-field)
But I'm not understanding this part(and my code is all not working :c)

```
$('input.inputFile').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).siblings('span').text(val);
})
```

**Here is what I've tried:**

```js
$("span.Anexo input").addClass('inputFile');

$("span").click(function() {

  $("input.inputFile'").trigger('click');
  
});

$('input.inputFile').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).siblings('span').text(val);
})
```

```css
span.Anexo label{ display: none;}
input#fu89_1_14_0{display: none;}
span#formContato_ctl00_rptAba_rptSessao_0_rptCampos_0_ctl00_6 {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    border: 3px dotted #009997;
    background-color:red;
    padding: 0.5em 1.1em;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-transition: border 500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: border 500ms ease-out;
    transition: border 500ms ease-out;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span#formContato_ctl00_rptAba_rptSessao_0_rptCampos_0_ctl00_6:hover{border-color: white;}
span#formContato_ctl00_rptAba_rptSessao_0_rptCampos_0_ctl00_6:before {
    background: url(someincon.svg) no-repeat;
    content: 'Clique aqui para enviar o arquivo';
    line-height: 3.2;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4em;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Anexo">
  <label>Anexo:</label>
  <input type="file" name="ctl00$formContato$ctl00$rptAba$ctl00$rptSessao$ctl00$rptCampos$ctl06$fu89_1_14_0" id="fu89_1_14_0">
  <span id="formContato_ctl00_rptAba_rptSessao_0_rptCampos_0_ctl00_6">
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048026/open-file-dialog-box-in-javascript

Comment: @xadhix I think, use an opacity can be an option, but I still wanna know What I can do with this structure. The question I've linked on this post, is not working with me(I think it's caused by the HTML structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple spans which are having the same class. so it is giving an error.

Replace your Code with This script. it will open a file dialog when you click on Anexo.

```
       $("#Anexo").click(function() {
           $("#fu89_1_14_0").trigger('click');
       });

       $('#fu89_1_14_0').on('change', function() {
           var val = $(this).val();
           $(this).siblings('span').text(val);
       })
```

HTML Code

```
  <span class="Anexo">
   <span class="Anexo">
    <label id="Anexo">Anexo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="ctl00$formContato$ctl00$rptAba$ctl00$rptSessao$ctl00$rptCampos$ctl06$fu89_1_14_0" id="fu89_1_14_0">
    <span id="formContato_ctl00_rptAba_rptSessao_0_rptCampos_0_ctl00_6" style="display:none;">
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: I only have one class named "Anexo" on <span>. My span is styled with an image on background, and also I can't change my HTML structure. So I just wanna get the trigger from my input, like the link of the question I got my script.

Comment: I hadn't change your html structure I Just assign and id to anexo label and changed jquery function with Id